# Initiating a Webhook connection to a secure API endpoint utilizing an X.509 certificate in Google DialogFlow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, x509certificate, x509, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

A chatbot we created in Google DialogFlow needs to make API calls (GET and POST) to obtain important personal data from a remote server, so the connection needs to be secured with an X.509 certificate.

Right now we are utilizing the DialogFlow Inline editor to make data request calls internally to a Firebase database, but puzzled with changing this set-up to connect to a remote server instead.

Would anyone be so kind to provide any guidance how to implement such a secure integration via an X.509 certificate to make API calls, please?

Comment: I this doc --> (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-mtls) there is a demo on how to achieve it with Node.js. You may find useful information regarding this secure integration issue.